# Make a select2 created dynamically

Tags: javascript

I need to create another Select2 element but when I create the new one the previous one doesn't work.

```
function make(){
    $('.agregar_unidad').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).html().length!=27) {
            //$(this).children('select').select2("destroy");
        } else {
            $(this).html('<select class="itemNameUnidad" form-control id="nombre_Unidad_Ejecutora" name="itemName"></select>');
        }
        $(this).find('select').select2({
            placeholder: '--- Seleccione la unidad ---',
            alowClear:true,
            ajax: {
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/getUnidad',
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: so, what is not working?

Comment: when the new one is created the original stop working

Answer (score 1):

Because you are initializing all your select element in your DOM. That's why it is affecting the first select with the settings you initialized to it.

Try to initialize your script to:

```
$('.agregar_unidad').closest('select').select2({settings})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nombre = 0;
function refresh(){
 $( ".agregar_unidad" ).last().html('<select class="itemNameUnidad" form-control      id="nombre_Unidad_Ejecutora'+nombre+'" name="itemName"></select>');
     nombre++;
  $('.itemNameUnidad').last().select2({
    placeholder: '--- Seleccione la unidad ---',
    alowClear:true,
    ajax: {
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/getUnidad',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,

        processResults: function (data) {

            return {
                results: data
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }

});

         }
```

At the end this works for me, this is the solution a made, but if  you can tell me how do it better it would be nice cause Im just a student, thanks for the help...